# Iphone calendar push from my company application server(JAVA Environment)

Tags: java, iphone, calendar, icalendar

My company decided to use custom push of the iphone calendar from our application to the iphone users. We do not have MAC at our place and more over, no one here know how exactly to start developing. Can You please help us understand how to proceed. Any website/tutorial link will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that you want your application to schedule an event and have it entered on the iPhone calendar of the user?

Comment: No.. we are running an application on Jboss server(which has calendar for every user) we want to use the same data to display it in the iphone calendar when the user is off and not using the jboss server app.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to parse the calendar data with e.g. [iCal4j](http://ical4j.sourceforge.net/introduction.html) and publish it as link on your website or integrate it into your data flow. It seems that the API has kinda sync-function too.